# Select Query (Query table with same value using unique ID)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID   Value
1    A
2    A 
3    A
4    B
5    B
```

I like to make a select query where it returns all the rows that has the same value as the given ID.

For example, if I query ID=2, then it should return

```
ID  Value
1   A
2   A
3   A
```

If I query ID=5

```
ID  Value
4   B
5   B
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below sample query

```
 SELECT ID, Value from <tablename> WHERE Value=(SELECT Value from <tablename> WHERE ID=5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `WHERE` clause that makes a sub query to retrieve value for the given `id`.

```
SELECT Id, Value FROM `table` where Value=(SELECT Value FROM table WHERE Id=5)
```

Using `sub query` you can get all records that share the `same value` for the specified `id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE Value=(SELECT `Value` FROM `table` WHERE `ID`=2)
```